# Leave no selected date on Shiny daterange

Tags: r, shiny

I made a `daterange` in the code below, however as you will notice the start and end dates are already preset. Therefore, I would like to leave for both, "No selected date", as no dates has yet been defined.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

Test <- structure(
  list(dat= c("2021-01-01","2021-01-02","2021-01-03"),
       X= c(5,4,0)),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                    br(),
                    tabPanel("",
                             sidebarLayout(
                               sidebarPanel(
                                 uiOutput("daterange"),

                                 br()
                                 
                               ),
                               mainPanel(
                                   ),
                             ))
  ))

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  data <- reactive(Test)
  
  
  output$daterange <- renderUI({
    dateRangeInput("daterange1", "Period:",
                   start = min(data()$dat),
                   end   = max(data()$dat),
                   min   = min(data()$dat),
                   max   = max(data()$dat),
                   format = "dd-mm-yyyy")
  })
    

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Set `start` and `end` to `NA`.

Comment: Thanks for reply Limey. NA leaves the field empty, but would like to leave it written: "No selected date" instead of leaving the field empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One hacky solution is to add some JavaScript to put the "No selected date" just after the creation of the `dateRangeInput`.

```R
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

Test <- structure(
  list(dat= c("2021-01-01","2021-01-02","2021-01-03"),
       X= c(5,4,0)),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

ui <- fluidPage(
  shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE, br(),
        tabPanel("",sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel( uiOutput("daterange"), br()),
            mainPanel()
        ))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  data <- reactive(Test)
  output$daterange <- renderUI({
    tagList(dateRangeInput("daterange1", "Period:",
                   start = min(data()$dat),
                   end   = max(data()$dat),
                   min   = min(data()$dat),
                   max   = max(data()$dat),
                   format = "dd-mm-yyyy"),
            tags$script(HTML('
                setTimeout(function(){
                  $("#daterange1 input")[0].value = "No selected date";
                  $("#daterange1 input")[1].value = "No selected date";
                }, 50);
            '))
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```